# as3 - player moves through objects

Tags: actionscript-3

So I'm making a collision detection when player touches an object. When it touches the object, you move and stop when colliding, but for example, if I press the D key to go right, and I press the A key and let go, then the player starts moving through the object.

This is my player moving code.

```
public function onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent): void
{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
    {
        isRight = true;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.A)
    {
        isLeft = true;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.W)
    {
        isUp = true;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.S)
    {
        isDown = true;
    }
}

private function onKeyUp(event: KeyboardEvent): void
    {
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.A || event.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
        {
            vx = 0;
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.S || event.keyCode == Keyboard.W)
        {
            vy = 0;
        }
    }

public function onEnterFrame(event: Event): void
{
    if (isRight)
    {
        vx = 5;
        x += vx;
    }
    if (isLeft)
    {
        vx = 5;
        x -= vy;
    }
    if (isUp)
    {
        vx = 5;
        y -= vy;
    }
    if (isDown)
    {
        vx = 5;
        y += vy;
    }

    //collision detection
        if (player.collisionArea.hitTestObject(wall0))
        {
            player.x -= vx;
            player.y -= vy;
        }
}
```

Comment: What are `vx` and `vy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue, is that `vx` is always `5`.  So one direction you subtract `5` from the `x`,  the other direction you add it.

Yet in your collision if statement, you are always subtracting it from the player's `x` (which if moving left, would keep moving the player left until it's past the object it's colliding with).

Also, in your `isLeft` check, you are subtracting the `vy` value, but I imagine you want to actually subtract the `vx` value.  On that same note, in your `isUp`/`isDown` checks, your set the `vx` var to `5`, but it seems like you should be setting the `vy`.

As it's unclear what `x` and `y` affect in context to the player, it's hard to give you an exact code example.

Most likely, you just need to move the player to the wall edge, and choose the side based off the direction of the player:

```
    //collision detection
    if (player.collisionArea.hitTestObject(wall0))
    {

        //if the player x is colliding
        if(player.x + player.width > wall0.x && player.x < wall0.x + wall0.width){
            player.x = isRight ? wall0.x - player.width : wall0.x + wall0.width;
        }else if(player.y + player.height > wall0.y && player.y < wall0.y + wall0.height){
            player.y = isDown ? wall0.y - player.height : wall0.y + wall0.height;
        }
    }
```

Comment: is there a way for it to still slide side by side when hitting the y part of the wall, and slide up and down when hitting the x side of the wall? that way we dont get stuck when touching the wall.

Comment: Updated the code slightly to address that.  Though it wouldn't be an issue in the first code block.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. When player collides with the y part, and i try to move x position while pressing up or down. it get's stuck and i cant move the x position, vice versa too.

Comment: Yes, but what is the nature of your wall? You haven't given many details about the nature of your program.  Do you have multiple walls that are rectangular in nature?  One wall object that has a series of shapes inside it?  Multiple complex wall shapes?  From your comments it seems clear that you want diagonal movement.  It's completely unclear what setting `x` and `y` do,  scrolling the camera I'd have to guess.  Please provide more details if you want a better answer

Comment: No, it doesn't scroll the camera. My player moves and the stage follows it. And the wall is just a simple square. Not multiple objects.

Comment: Your stage is acting like a camera then so yes that's what I mean.  I've updated the answer to judge the x and y separately.  This all assumes you have top left registration points for all your objects.